# Php Do-While not cycling

Tags: php, ebay-api

I have this part of code used to check if a file is ready to download from Ebay Large Merchant Service

```
$retry = 0;
do {
    if ($retry > 0){sleep(5);}
    $response = $session->sendBulkDataExchangeRequest('getJobStatus',$getJobStatusRequestXml);
    $xml = simplexml_load_string($response);

    if(!empty($xml) && 'Success' == (string)$xml->ack)
    {
        $jobStatus = (string)$xml->jobProfile->jobStatus;  
        $completionTime = (string)$xml->jobProfile->completionTime;
        $percentComplete = (string)$xml->jobProfile->percentComplete;
        $fileReferenceId = (string)$xml->jobProfile->fileReferenceId;
        $taskReferenceId = (string)$xml->jobProfile->jobId;
    }
    $retry++;
} while ($jobStatus == 'Completed' || $retry >=10);
```

... Others functions to download file...

sendBulkDataExchangeRequest do and API call to check jobStatus.

I need to repeat this call untill jobStatus is Completed or (to skip infinite loop) if retry is => 10 but it doesnt work and try to download the file (next function after do-while) also if jobStatus is InProcess or Scheduled.

Where I'm wrong?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your while condition is the wrong way round - this will continue 'while' the status is completed or retry >= 10.

You probably want

```
while ($jobStatus != 'Completed' && $retry <10);
```

which says repeat while the job isn't completed and the retry count is less than 10.

Comment: I owe you a coffee !